# Multilanguage website - Pure PHP

Tags: php, html, localization, multilingual

I should make a new feature - ability to choose languages to a website which is in pure PHP.

Here I completely understand that it would be much better to use frameworks, however, by some specific reasons, it was not me who decided to use pure PHP and I don't have a full access to a server.

---

So, I've developed the system that changes languages by using `$_SESSION` and it works just fine. I will not describe a full implementation of that, because that's an easy part.

**The main question is**, how to replace strings in HTML pages using that system and can someone tell me if I'm doing it right? Is there a better way in performance / comfort of using?

---

**Here is what I do:**

I have a class `session`, which determines which language the user is actually using. Then, as soon as he "understands" which it is, `seession` class loads **JSON** file from a folder `lang` with an array of words.

And `session` is ready to go.

So here is a simple example of using in HTML:

```
<html lang="<?php echo(session::$lang['Info']['LangCode']); ?>">  // pt-PT - portuguese, en-EN - English etc...
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li><?php echo(session::$lang['Simple']['Categories']); ?></li>
         <li><?php echo(session::$lang['Simple']['LogIn']); ?></li>
       </ul>
       <button><?php echo(session::$lang['Simple']['AddToCart']); ?></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

It definitely works. But I want to know if using the system like this one is ok and if there are better ways of doing so, which they could be? So one more time - pure PHP.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Build a Multilingual App](https://www.toptal.com/php/build-multilingual-app-with-gettext)

Comment: Normally I would say there are better ways, in fact: Use a library for that or us a CMS. But in your case your solution looks as a very good compromise.